# returning a list of a type from parsing a byte stream in which the length is not known until runtime

Tags: haskell, types, binary, bytestring

I think this is more of my lack of understanding the intricacy of Types than anything else.  Trying to solve this I feel that I've been close a couple of times but not there yet.

I am trying to read from a stream using Data.Binary.  I've reached a point in which the next section could have one or more of a chunk, but information isn't known until you start parsing the stream.  I am having issues returning those multiple chunks.

Here is the code, and if I going about this the wrong way please let me know.  But keep in mind that I need to be able to easily use the same scaffolding to write back to the stream.

Possibly Helpful Information:

- The stream is a PE File
- I am using lenses (fclabels)
- The DataDirectory type is nested a few levels deep within other types.

> ```
> data DataDirectory = 
>   DataDirectory { _dataEntryList ::  [DataEntry] } deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
>
> data DataEntry = DataEntry
>   { _virtAddr :: Word32            -- VirtualAddress ^ relative virtual address of the table
>   , _size :: Word32                -- Size ^ size of the table in bytes
>   } deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
>
> parseDataDir :: Word32 -> Get DataDirectory
> parseDataDir n = do
>   -- PE Files have a maximum of 16 sections in the DataDir
>   -- most windows tools just set this to 16 by default
>   -- instead of hard-coding 16 sections we will verify
>   let nDirs = fromIntegral (min mAX_NUMBEROF_DIRECTORY_ENTRIES n) :: Int
>   dd_dentries <- parseDataEntry nDirs
>
>   return $ DataDirectory dd_dentries
>
> parseDataEntry :: Int -> [Get DataEntry] -- Not exactly sure on return type here
> parseDataEntry n = 
>   Prelude.replicate n $ getWord32le >>= \vAddr -> getWord32le >>= \ddSize -> return $ DataEntry vAddr ddSize
> ```

I have thus far avoided grabbing the entire stream and multiplying ***nDirs*** by 8 bytes to get the length and parse.  This certainly would work for this instance but possibly not downrange in other spots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Use Hoogle to search for the type you want.](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?q=Int+-%3E+Get+DataEntry+-%3E+Get+%5BDataEntry%5D)

Comment: Beautiful, that's the stuff. Thank you Daniel.  The answer is using replicateM from Control.Monad which itself just uses a monadic version of sequence.